# How to set textlabels of UITableView cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

In my app, I have a map that allows the user to drop pins onto the map. The pins geocode the address and set the address as their title. I made it so that the annotations are stored in an array when they are dropped. I have a tableview, that I want to show the addresses in the cells. I have an array in the tableview class that points to the array in the first view controller, and I somehow need to access the addresses from the array and set them as the textlabels of the cells. I already have the table view display as many cells as there are pins on the map, but I do not know how to access the information I need from the array. Here is some code to help.

Here is the first view controller:

```
@implementation P2OViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    NSInteger mapTypeValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                              integerForKey:P2OMapTypePrefKey];

    // Update the UI
    [mapTypeControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:mapTypeValue];

    // Update the map
    [self changeMapType:mapTypeControl];


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self
                                                                                         action:@selector(press:)];
    [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:0.5f]; //user needs to press for 2 seconds
    [longPress setDelegate:self];
    [_worldView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    _annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    [_worldView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    number =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

}

-(void)press:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:_worldView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [_worldView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:_worldView];

    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate
                                                    altitude:CLLocationDistanceMax
                                          horizontalAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                                            verticalAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                                                   timestamp:[NSDate date]];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:completionHandler: called");
                       if (error) {
                           NSLog(@"Geocoder failed with error: %@", error);
                       } else {
                           CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                           geocodedAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@ %@", [place subThoroughfare], [place thoroughfare], [place locality], [place administrativeArea]];
                           if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == [recognizer state]) {
                               value = [number intValue];
                               number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value + 1];
                               addressPin = [[MapPoint alloc]initWithAddress:geocodedAddress coordinate:touchMapCoordinate
                                                                   title:geocodedAddress identifier:number];
                               NSLog(@"The identifier is %@", number);
                               [_annotationArray addObject:addressPin];
                               [_worldView addAnnotation:addressPin];
                               NSLog(@"The number of pins in the annotation array is: %u",_annotationArray.count);
                           }
                       }
                   }];
}


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    PinViewController *pvc = [[PinViewController alloc]init];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:pvc
                                      animated:YES];
    pvc.label.text = view.annotation.title;
}  

- (IBAction)bookmarkPressed:(id)sender
{
    P2OTableViewViewController *tvc = [[P2OTableViewViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [tvc setValue:_annotationArray];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:tvc
                                      animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Here is my TableViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class P2OViewController;

@interface P2OTableViewViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *_pinArray;
    __weak P2OViewController *_pvc;
}

@property (readonly) UILabel *textLabel;
@property (weak,nonatomic) P2OViewController *pvc;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pinArray;

-(void)setValue:(NSMutableArray *)value;
@end

@implementation P2OTableViewViewController

@synthesize pinArray = _pinArray, pvc = _pvc;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        _pinArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setValue:(NSMutableArray *)value
{
   _pinArray  = value;
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _pinArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

So basically I want the title of the annotations in the array to be the textlabel for the cells. So if there are 5 pins in the array, I want the 5 cells to have the corresponding addresses of the annotations (the title property) as the textlabels. I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `return cell;`, you can do `cell.textLabel.text = [_pinArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` Make sure you're extracting the title property from _pinArray.

Comment: @ChandlerDeAngelis FYI: also there's detail text label in cell for any detail on ur title.  cell.detailTextLabel.text.